# Welchen deutschen Ausdruck könnten Sie für "Änderungsmodus" im Zusammenhang mit Linux-Shell-Skripten verwenden?

Tags: technical-terminology

Welchen deutschen Ausdruck könnten Sie für "Änderungsmodus" im Zusammenhang mit Linux-Shellskripten verwenden?

Es gibt einen Linuxbefehl namens `chmod`, der auf Englisch "**change mode**" ("Modus ändern") bedeutet.

- Verzeichnis erstellen
- Verzeichnis
- Modus ändern
- Modalität mutieren
- Verzeichnis erstellen
- Modus ändern
- Modalität mutieren

Meine Motivation bezieht sich auf die Computerprogrammierung. Das englische Wort „shell“ bedeutet so viel wie Hülle, Bonbonpapier oder Einwickelpapier.

Meine Motivation, diese Frage zu stellen, ist, dass ich Code für eine Bonbonverpackung schreiben kann, die die Bourne-Again-Schale verpacken soll.

Die Leute könnten "**change mod**" `chmod` in französisch, Englisch, deutsch oder jeder anderen europäischen Sprache eingeben.

Unser Bonbonpapier (**wrapper**) würde den deutschen Ausdruck für "Seinszustand ändern" in `chmod` umwandeln und `chmod` in BASH (die wiedergeborene Shell) übergeben.

Wenn Sie die Neigung dazu haben, überarbeiten Sie bitte die schlechte Grammatik, die ich in meiner Frage verwendet habe.

Comment: Leider ist die Frage etwas schwer verständlich - ist mit "Code für eine Bonbonverpackung" gemeint, dass ein Shell-Skript geschrieben werden soll? (Das Wort "Bonbonverpackung" würde hierfür niemand verwenden - nicht einmal das allgemeinere "Verpackung".) Oder ist hier absichtlich ein Wortwitz, der auf die mögliche (wenn auch ungebräuchliche) Übersetzung von "shell" als "Verpackung" abzielt, und bewusst das deutsche (ungebräuchliche) Wort an einer Stelle verwendet, wo eine Shell aus der Informatik gemeint ist?

Comment: bash - Bourne Again Shell. Das ist nach dem Erfinder / Programmierer benannt und nicht die Born again shell.

Comment: Beim erneuten Lesen fällt mir auf, dass der (in jedem Fall hierfür ungebräuchliche und auch unnötig spezifische - wieso denn gerade *Bonbons*?) deutsche Begriff "Bonbonverpackung" in der Frage offenbar sowohl mit "Shell" als auch mit "Wrapper" gleichgesetzt wird. Das sind meines Erachtens zwei unterschiedliche Konzepte (oder zumindest implizieren sie einen anderen Kontext).

Comment: Feel free to ask questions in English. This one sounds like it was created using a machine translator (or by a person painstakingly translating word for word and always choosing the first option to translate e.g. "wrapper").

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to solve or achive with your project? I In german the english names (wrapper, shell) are common terms in IT language. Nobody would call a shell "Schale". I really hate using english terms in everyday speech - but in programming this is a great way to avoid ambiguities. Shell - it's clear what you mean, not that bowl (= Schale) of apples on the table. So I think it is not a good idea to translate shell commands into other languages. "chmod" - ah that! "Ändere Rechte" - what? Trying to solve problems that don't exist will make things complicated, not easy :-)

Comment: @planetmaker: Die Bourneshell war in der Tat nach dem Programmierer benannt, die Bourne-Again-Shell (Brian Fox) dagegen beinhaltet durchaus den Wortwitz mit der Wiedergeburt (vielleicht auch "brenn noch einmal!"). Der Befehl `type chmod` zeigt jedoch: `chmod ist /usr/bin/chmod` also keine bashinterne Funktion ist, sondern ein separates Programm und wird mutmaßlich genauso aus ash, sh, zsh, dash, fish usw. aufgerufen.

Comment: Siehe auch https://youtu.be/KNxdmBqcVyk?t=856

Comment: @puck I wanted to write a small library which would allow people to type `chmod` written in many different languages. As long as what the person typed in was half-way reasonable, then the output would be `chmod`. My idea was that people could type in a subsequence of `change` and then type in a subsequence of the word `mode`  For example, someone could type in `chmod` or `chgmd` or `change mode` or `Modus ändern` or `Mdärn`. I could write code for 100 or 200 different Linux and/or Unix commands. It might be useful for students who have spent less than one year doing computer programming.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I do see what you want to do, but not why or what problems it would solve. Almost everyone speaks english, at least those who want to work with computers in a way that requires shell programming. *"It might be useful for students"* - really?  You make people think things work this way - later they will see it's wrong, they would produce incompatible code and would have to learn everything again from start. This is all but helpful. Don't fool them ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Mein Vorschlag ist

> Zugriffsrechte ändern

Das passt zwar für `+x` nicht so richtig, wird aber ziemlich sicher verstanden.

Comment: +x ist doch auch ein Zugriffsrecht - das Recht, die Datei auszuführen. Die man-pages nennen es Dateimodusbits ändern

Answer (score 3):

Debian has a [manpages-l10n](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/manpages-l10n/4.18.0-1/) package. You can read the German translations online at https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-de/index.html. For `chmod`, it says

> chmod - Dateimodusbits ändern

Answer (score 2):

Die Reihenfolge der Substantive ist verkehrt. Es muss Modusänderung, nicht Änderungsmodus heißen.

Ohne Erklärung wird man womöglich nicht erschließen, was gemeint ist, wenn dies beispielsweise in einem Kontextmenü auftaucht.

Gängige Übersetzungen sind jedoch, wie bereits empfohlen, Zugriffsrechte/Dateiberechtigungen ändern.